# Why does't the following Javascript sort code work?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am using jquery to extract text of a set of elements into an array and want to sort them after inserting an element into the array. However, the sort is not working (as in the array remains in the same order after the sort). What's wrong? Code excerpt is below:

```
var sortedList = [];
$("div.resource").each(function(i, item) {
    var resource = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    sortedList.push(resource);
})

// Add the new item 
sortedList.push(resource_name.toLowerCase());

alert("before sort");
for (var i = 0; i < sortedList.length; i++) {
    alert(sortedList[i]);
}

// Sort the list
sorted = sortedList.sort();

alert("after sort");
for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    alert(sorted[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please, create an example with some array itens...

Comment: Instead of alerting in a loop, you can just `console.log` the array... (`console.log(sorted);`)

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rxRFm/

Comment: @davidbuzatto I am not sure I understand your comment. I already tested that sort works fine when it is given a hardcoded array of strings like so: `var array = ["test", "fry", "aba"];`.

Comment: Btw, I think you forgot to declare the variable `sorted`.

Comment: For me too. You just need to call sort() in the original array. You don't need to assign its return.

Comment: You're using `.html()` so you might be getting HTML tags in there (if the elements have children).  Try using `.text()` instead.  Also, try to `$.trim()` the strings.

Comment: Where does resource_name come from? It's probably not related to your problem, but I'm just curious; as you're going through each element and adding the contents to the array - but then you're adding this other parameter to the array. However, the main point is that you're adding the HTML of the element to the array - not the actual text contents. So try it using .text() not .html().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
var sortedList = [];
$("div.resource").each(function(i, item) {
    var resource = $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase();
    sortedList.push(resource);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestions to use text() instead of html() and to trim the strings, wrap everything in the jQuery Document Ready function which will give the elements and jQuery library time to load (if you haven't already done that).

Beyond that it could be a browser issue.  It works for me in chrome using both html() and text().  Though I made sure the elements only have text in them.

Also probably not a huge issue but your .each() method is missing a semi-colon.